# font rendering compatibility between os'es

Tags: html, css, firefox, microsoft-edge, antialiasing

I'm working on a website and today I'm doing compatibility testing. What I notice is that font-rendering is different between OS X and Windows. Is there any way to fix this or is there a way to use different stylesheets based on OS's. 
I will attach the screenshots from different browsers and different OS'es

chrome mac: [image: chrome mac]

chrome win: [image: chrome win]

firefox mac: [image: firefox mac]

firefox win: [image: firefox win]

opera mac: [image: opera mac]

safari mac: [image: safari mac]

edge win: [image: internet explorer win]

I am using `Open Sans` webkit font embedding from google fonts.
The site is made in Wordpress and the body has anti-aliasing enabled (`-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`).

Basic outcome: looks good on windows and firefox mac but really not readable on chrome, opera and safari for mac.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this issue?

Comment: Are you wondering about the variance in size or only quality?